# Error when install pandas with Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install new pandas version to my company's PC. Because my computer cannot connect to the internet so I downloaded the file `tar.gz` and use Anaconda Prompt to install but encountered the following problem:

```
(base) C:\Users\admin>pip install pandas-2.1.4.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\admin\pandas-2.1.4.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4ynsmtd4\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- meson-python==0.13.1 meson==1.2.1 wheel 'Cython>=0.29.33,<3' 'oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16; python_version<'"'"'3.12'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.26.0,<2; python_version>='"'"'3.12'"'"'' 'versioneer[toml]'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (8 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.12"' don't match your environment
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002775E8F02E0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/meson-python/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002775E8F04F0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/meson-python/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002775E8F06A0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/meson-python/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002775E8F0850>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/meson-python/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002775E8F0A00>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/meson-python/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement meson-python==0.13.1
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for meson-python==0.13.1
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///C:/Users/admin/pandas-2.1.4.tar.gz. Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4ynsmtd4\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- meson-python==0.13.1 meson==1.2.1 wheel 'Cython>=0.29.33,<3' 'oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16; python_version<'"'"'3.12'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.26.0,<2; python_version>='"'"'3.12'"'"'' 'versioneer[toml]' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4ynsmtd4\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- meson-python==0.13.1 meson==1.2.1 wheel 'Cython>=0.29.33,<3' 'oldest-supported-numpy>=2022.8.16; python_version<'"'"'3.12'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.26.0,<2; python_version>='"'"'3.12'"'"'' 'versioneer[toml]' Check the logs for full command output.
```

As I understand I need to update new python version of Python too, but I don't know how. How can I solve this problem? (Please note that I just can use Anaconda in my PC). Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

[You can learn about updating python here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-update-python/).

Additionally however the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement meson-python==0.13.1
```

means that your computer cannot find version 0.13.1 of meson-python, which is required by pandas-2.1.4. If you have no internet connection then your computer may not be able to find that version (even though [it definitely exists](https://pypi.org/project/meson-python/0.13.1/)). So you'll need to get that onto your computer as well.